# How do I get the username and password field into a Blackberry Text Box? 

Tags: java, blackberry

How do I get the username and password field into a text box?

```
usernameField = new EditField("USERNAME:", "");
passwordField = new PasswordEditField("PASSWORD:", "");
add(usernameField);
vm.add(new LabelField("\n"));
add(passwordField);
ButtonField buttonField_1 = new ButtonField( "Login",ButtonField.FIELD_HCENTER );
add( buttonField_1 );   
ButtonField buttonField_2 = new ButtonField( "Forgot Password",ButtonField.FIELD_HCENTER );
add( buttonField_2 );   
buttonField_1.setMargin(100, 10, 10, 10);
//popup1();
buttonField_1.setChangeListener( new FieldChangeListener() {
    public void fieldChanged( Field arg0, int arg1 ) {
        if (usernameField.getTextLength() == 0 || passwordField.getTextLength() == 0) {
            Dialog.alert("You must enter a username and password");
        } else {
            profile();
        }
    }
});

buttonField_2.setChangeListener( new FieldChangeListener() {
    public void fieldChanged( Field arg0, int arg1 ) {
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new Forgot_Pwd());
    }
});
```

Comment: Explain you question. Use `usernameField.getText()` and `passwordField.getText()` to retrieve text from `EditField`, `PasswordEditField`. What did you mean by `into a text box`?

Comment: If you are fetching data from some database or from other classes you can use settext() method on EditField or PasswordField is this what you want otherwise explain question that we know, what you want actually.

Comment: I want to make a round rect and put these field into them

Comment: Like in a black background there will be a white rectangle in the centre with these two fields inside it

Answer (score 2):

http://keraisureshvblackberry.blogspot.in/2012/02/on-last-post-we-have-study-lablefiled.html

This blog is help to you for create username and password textbox

if you getting text from filed than you can use
**usernameField.getText()** and **passwordField.getText()**

Answer (score 0):

[TextField - show hint before user starts typing text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393951/textfield-show-hint-before-user-starts-typing-text)

You can try that link.It'll aid to make boxes but even i've been struggling trying to create one same as u r suggesting.If anyone has some more ideas,it would be much appreciated.