# Place holder text on a AutoCompleteField in blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry, autocomplete

I have tp place a `AutoCompleteField` in one of my screen in Blackberry app. I have to show a place holder text to provide hint for user to enter the information.

Here is the below code of `AutoCompleteField`

```
BasicFilteredList filterList = new BasicFilteredList();
        String[] address = { "T 115 Centro Galleria Shopping Centre, Cnr Old Collier and Walters Road Morley WA 1522", 
                "1423 SEAVIEW POINT POINT COOK VIC 2674",
                "Lot 1498 Yarraman Road Wyndham Vale VIC 3795", 
                "Lot 3506 Witchmount Close Hillside VIC 4055",
                "6 Paas Place Williamstown VIC 4233", 
                "Lot 99 14 James Close Sunbury VIC 4502", 
                "1 Charlotte Street Clayton South VIC 4779" };

        filterList.addDataSet(1, address, "address", BasicFilteredList.COMPARISON_IGNORE_CASE);
        AutoCompleteField autoCompleteField = new AutoCompleteField(filterList){
            public void onSelect(Object selection, int SELECT_TRACKWHEEL_CLICK) {
                 ListField _list = getListField();
                 if (_list.getSelectedIndex() > -1) {
                     if(selectedText!=null){
                         BasicFilteredListResult result = (BasicFilteredListResult) selection;
                         selectedText.setText(result._object.toString());
                     }
                 }
             }
        };
        add(autoCompleteField);
```

Anyone, please suggest me how could I implement the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a similar technique to [the one shown here for normal EditFields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7414401/119114).  Basically, you need to override the `paint()` method in an `AutoCompleteField` subclass.  In `paint()`, you check and see if the field is empty, and if so, you manually draw the *placeholder* text you want.

The difference is that `AutoCompleteField` is a `Manager` with a `BasicEditField` inside of it.  So, to draw the text properly, you need to figure out the x and y offsets of the edit field within the parent `Manager` (the `AutoCompleteField`).

So, replace your `AutoCompleteField` instance with an instance of this class:

```
   private class CustomAutoCompleteField extends AutoCompleteField {
      private int yOffset = 0;
      private int xOffset = 0;

      public CustomAutoCompleteField(BasicFilteredList filteredList) {
         super(filteredList);
      }

      protected void paint(Graphics g) {
         super.paint(g);
         if (xOffset == 0) {
            // initialize text offsets once
            xOffset = getEditField().getContentLeft();
            yOffset = getEditField().getContentTop();
         }
         String text = getEditField().getText();
         if (text == null || text.length() == 0) {
            int oldColor = g.getColor();
            g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            g.drawText("enter text", xOffset, yOffset);
            g.setColor(oldColor);
         }
      }

      public void onSelect(Object selection, int SELECT_TRACKWHEEL_CLICK) {
         ListField _list = getListField();
         if (_list.getSelectedIndex() > -1) {
            if(selectedText!=null){
               BasicFilteredListResult result = (BasicFilteredListResult) selection;
               selectedText.setText(result._object.toString());
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

I tested this on OS 5.0, with an instance that didn't have any margin or padding set.  It's possible that with different layouts, you may need to adjust the logic for calculating the x and y offsets.  But, the above code shows you the basic idea.  Good luck.

**Edit:** the above code is presented with the caveat that your `onSelect()` method is clearly relying on code not shown.  As is, the above code won't compile.  I left `onSelect()` in there just to show that I'm essentially just replacing the anonymous class you originally had, and not doing anything different in your `onSelect()` method, as it's not directly related to the placeholder text issue.